# Convert NSTextField to NSImage?

Tags: cocoa

Is there any way of creating a NSImage from a NSTextField? I am making an app that should capture user text and generate PNG files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, let the view draw into an image:

```
-(NSImage *)imageOfView:(NSView*)view
{
 NSRect myRect = view.bounds;
 NSSize imgSize = myRect.size;

 NSBitmapImageRep *bir = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:myRect];
 [bir setSize:mySize];
 [view cacheDisplayInRect:myRect toBitmapImageRep:bir];

 NSImage* image = [[[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:mySize] autorelease];
 [image addRepresentation:bir];
 return image;
}
```

from http://www.stairways.com/blog/2009-04-21-nsimage-from-nsview

---

if you only want the STRING, render it yourself using NSString's drawString method like this:

```
-(NSImage *)imageWithText(NSString*)string:
{
 NSSize mySize = NSMakeSize(50,100); //or measure the string

 NSBitmapImageRep *bir = NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
    initWithBitmapDataPlanes:(unsigned char **)&bitmapArray
    pixelsWide:mySize.width pixelsHigh:mySize.height
    bitsPerSample:8
    samplesPerPixel:3  // or 4 with alpha
    hasAlpha:NO
    isPlanar:NO
    colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
    bitmapFormat:0
    bytesPerRow:0  // 0 == determine automatically
    bitsPerPixel:0];  // 0 == determine automatically

    //draw text using -(void)drawInRect:(NSRect)aRect withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes

 NSImage* image = [[[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:mySize] autorelease];
 [image addRepresentation:bir];
 return image;
}
```

Comment: Sounds promishing but how I specify what NSTextField I want to render? I have several defined as IBOutlet NSTextField *label00, *label01, and I want to generate a NSImage from each one. Thanks!

Comment: modified imageOfView: now takes  a view -- you pass it the textField. e.g. [self imageOfView:label00];

Comment: `NSMakeSize( mySize.width, mySize.height )` is unnecessary, since `mySize` is already a size. You could just use `mySize` for the initializer.

Comment: sorry, copy&paste error as I wrote the code is partly from the above blog, Ill fix that

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5:

```
  private func convertTextFieldToImage() -> NSImage? {
    let myRect = timerLabel.bounds
    let mySize = myRect.size

    guard let bitmapImageRepresentation = timerLabel.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: myRect) else {
      return nil
    }
    bitmapImageRepresentation.size = mySize
    timerLabel.cacheDisplay(in: myRect, to: bitmapImageRepresentation)

    let image = NSImage(size: mySize)
    image.addRepresentation(bitmapImageRepresentation)

    return image
  }
```